# validation rule on multi select picklist at least one select

Tags: validation-rule, multi-select

I have a multi select picklist which has 6 items. Now I have to implement  validation rule that "at least one picklist item selected" and this validation rule should be fired only when the `status__c` is 'Draft'

I'm not sure how to combine this two into one rule

I have attempted something like this:

```
IF( ISPICKVAL( status__c , 'Draft'), IF(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist__c, "A"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist__c, "B"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist__c, "C"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist__c, "D"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist__c, "E"),1,0) => 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for the field being blank and Status being draft:

```
isblank('Multi_Picklist__c')&&IsPickVal(Status__c,'Draft')
```